# fetching data from more than tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a textbox in a serach page where i enter the name  of company, and I want that when I enter company Name e.g "abc" in the textbox, then it gave `user's name` from users table and company name from the profession table: Below is the search page controller:

```
def search
    @students=Students.all
    if ( !params[:tf_Company].blank? or params[:tf_Company] !="" )
      @user_Company= User.joins(:professions).where(:professions => {:Company=> params[:tf_Company].strip}).collect(&:First_Name)
    end     

    render 'search'
  end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Profession  model**

```
class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :UserID, presence: true
end
```

I am getting an error below:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: professions.user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "professions" ON "professions"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "professions"."Designation" = 'Lead'
```

But its not working fine, kindly help me, waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your models and their associations please

Comment: What does "its not working fine" mean? Do you get errors or not the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join condition is looking for foreign_key `user_id` in `professions` table which unfortunately does not exist. Hence, the error.

Looking at the `Profession` model, I am assuming that you did include a foreign_key in `professions` table but named it as `UserID`.

I would suggest you to stick with the rails convention of having foreign_key as `associationname_id` which in our case would be `user_id`.

BUT if you still want to go for `UserID` as foreign_key then specify it in `both sides of association` as below:

```
class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :UserID
    validates :UserID, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professions, foreign_key: :UserID, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: I am using your post, but the same error still came.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Specify foreign_key on both sides of association. Try that and let me know if it fixes your issue.